# availability of page numbers

Tags: support

## 1.  Could we please select a page number both at the top of the page as well as the bottom?

## 2  Could we have a button that could be selected, after we view an individual questions and its responses, that will take us back to where we were before without having to start all over at the beginning?

Comment: Doesn't the 'back' button in your browser work for #2? It does for me.